# Coding email footer module in Hubspot

Tags: html, css, email, global-variables, hubspot

I'm very new to coding and I'm trying to code only the footer of an email through hubspot - does anyone have experience creating modules on hubspot? I'm finding it really hard and I also don't know much about coding in emails.. Inline css is very annoying. Honestly, I know it looks like a mess. And can I even include HubL variables in html? Hubspot creates them for emails. Ugh Help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Footer</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
            table {border-collapse:separate;}
            a, a:link, a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #06AE8F;}
            a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
            h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited,h3,h3 a,h3 a:visited,h4,h5,h6,.t_cht {color:#ffffff;}
            .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td {line-height: 100%;}
            .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
      (min-device-width: 601px)
    width: 600px !important;

  .col380 {
    width: 380px!important;
}

  .col425 {
    width: 425px!important;
  }

  .col380 {
    width: 380px!important;
  }
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body yahoo="" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%;">
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <![endif]-->
          </td><td class="footer" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
              <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td align="center" class="footercopy" style="color: #C0C0C0; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly";>
                          <i>Copyright &copy; 2019 DonorSearch, All rights reserved.</i><br>
                          Our mailing address is:<br>
                          {{ site_settings.company_name }}<br>
                          {{ site_settings.company_street_address_1 }}<br>
                          {{ site_settings.company_city }}, {{ site_settings.company_state }} {{ site_settings.company_zip }}<br>
                          410-670-7880<br>
                          <a class="link1" a="" href="mailto:email@email.com" style="color: #D6B229; text-decoration: underline;">email@email.com</a><br>
                          Want to change how you receive these emails?<br>
                          <a class="link" a="" href="{{ unsubscribe_link }}" style="color: #06AE8F; text-decoration: underline;">You can update your preferences</a> or 
                          <a class="link" a="" href="{{ unsubscribe_link_all }}" style="color: #06AE8F; text-decoration: underline;"> Unsubscribe from mailing lists.</a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                        </tr></table></td>
                                  </tr>
                              </table>
                        </td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you articulate more clearly what your question is and you need fixed?  errors?

Comment: @Nelles I guess I'm asking - when looking at my code, is what i've written correct in order to display correctly over all the different email clients - for example, yahoo, gmail, etc.